# How to support named data entries in Windows Event Log events with .NET?

Tags: .net, event-log

Windows event log seems to support named data entries in event log events. However I cannot find how to write these events with .NET.

Example of such entries:

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
   <System>
     <Security /> 
   </System>
   <EventData>
     <Data Name="SubjectUserSid">S-1-5-18</Data> 
     <Data Name="SubjectUserName">DAVE-PC$</Data> 
   </EventData>
</Event>
```

Is there any way to do this from BCL? Or only PInvoke?